# \phantom ignored at beginning of line (or line break inserted)

Tags: line-breaking, indentation, phantom

In a document, I tried to use `\phantom{}` to indent the next line. However, it seems the phantom part is removed and/or a line break inserted.

```
\documentclass[xcolor=pdftex,dvipsnames,table]{beamer} %

\begin{document}

\noindent X abc abc\\
X abc abc\\
\phantom{X} abc abc\\

\end{document}
```

This is what I get:

[image]

What I expected is the X to be invisible and the `abc`s to be aligned under to line above. Why is this not happening?

Comment: Use \leavevmode before the phantom to see why try with \hbox instead of phantom

Comment: It would be better to use a list than forcing spacing with noindent and phantt

Comment: Thanks, \leavevmode did the job, \hbox causes a line break. Could you elaborate on what happens here? I understand that there are better ways to achieve indentation, but I would like to understand what \phantom is doing. Obviously, not just "hiding" the content.